# Jenkins: Unexpected AbortException after End of Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I’m having an unexpected error in few of my builds, when ending the pipeline. The curious thing is that is affecting more than one environment (development and production). We thought it could be related to some plugin update, because we changed nothing in our Jenkins library since then.

Our scripts are differents, even the last part of the execution. But what they have in common is when ending, the very last part of the execution, when the pipeline is ended, then we have the follow error:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 29e6af80-d59a-4c2f-952a-8c19a6a8ed32
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 22
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:668)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:614)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:555)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.get(CpsBodyExecution.java:300)
    at com.mig82.folders.step.FolderPropertiesStep$Execution.run(FolderPropertiesStep.java:55)
    at com.mig82.folders.step.FolderPropertiesStep$Execution.run(FolderPropertiesStep.java:37)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate2(ACL.java:451)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I sincerely did not find similar error when searching for, so I’m asking here in case someone has an idea bout it. Thank you!

Jenkins setup:

```
Jenkins: 2.387.3
OS: Linux - 5.4.129+
Java: 11.0.19 - Eclipse Adoptium (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
---
ace-editor:1.1
active-directory:2.33
amazon-ecr:1.114.vfd22430621f5
amazon-ecs:1.48
anchore-container-scanner:1.0.25
ansicolor:1.0.3
ant:497.v94e7d9fffa_b_9
antisamy-markup-formatter:162.v0e6ec0fcfcf6
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.14-208.v438351942757
apache-httpcomponents-client-5-api:5.2.1-1.0
artifactory:3.18.9
authentication-tokens:1.53.v1c90fd9191a_b_
aws-credentials:218.v1b_e9466ec5da_
aws-java-sdk:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-codebuild:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-ec2:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-ecr:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-ecs:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-efs:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-iam:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-kinesis:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-logs:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-minimal:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-sns:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
aws-java-sdk-ssm:1.12.529-406.vdeff15e5817d
badge:1.9.1
basic-branch-build-strategies:81.v05e333931c7d
blueocean:1.27.3
blueocean-autofavorite:1.2.5
blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline:1.27.3
blueocean-commons:1.27.3
blueocean-config:1.27.3
blueocean-core-js:1.27.3
blueocean-dashboard:1.27.3
blueocean-display-url:2.4.2
blueocean-events:1.27.3
blueocean-git-pipeline:1.27.3
blueocean-github-pipeline:1.27.3
blueocean-i18n:1.27.3
blueocean-jira:1.27.3
blueocean-jwt:1.27.3
blueocean-personalization:1.27.3
blueocean-pipeline-api-impl:1.27.3
blueocean-pipeline-editor:1.27.3
blueocean-pipeline-scm-api:1.27.3
blueocean-rest:1.27.3
blueocean-rest-impl:1.27.3
blueocean-web:1.27.3
bootstrap4-api:4.6.0-6
bootstrap5-api:5.3.0-1
bouncycastle-api:2.29
branch-api:2.1122.v09cb_8ea_8a_724
build-monitor-plugin:1.14-744.v35fd6fa_a_26b_2
build-timeout:1.31
build-user-vars-plugin:1.9
buildtriggerbadge:251.vdf6ef853f3f5
caffeine-api:3.1.8-133.v17b_1ff2e0599
checkmarx:2023.2.6
checks-api:2.0.0
cloud-stats:316.vd6d6b_292238d
cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source:832.v43175a_425ea_6
cloudbees-folder:6.848.ve3b_fd7839a_81
cobertura:1.17
code-coverage-api:4.4.0
command-launcher:107.v773860566e2e
commons-lang3-api:3.13.0-62.v7d18e55f51e2
commons-text-api:1.10.0-68.v0d0b_c439292b_
conditional-buildstep:1.4.3
config-file-provider:953.v0432a_802e4d2
configuration-as-code:1670.v564dc8b_982d0
copyartifact:722.v0662a_9b_e22a_c
credentials:1271.v54b_1c2c6388a_
credentials-binding:631.v861c06d062b_4
cucumber-reports:5.7.5
custom-tools-plugin:0.8
dashboard-view:2.495.v07e81500c3f2
data-tables-api:1.13.5-1
disable-github-multibranch-status:1.2
display-url-api:2.3.9
docker-build-publish:1.4.0
docker-commons:439.va_3cb_0a_6a_fb_29
docker-java-api:3.3.1-79.v20b_53427e041
docker-plugin:1.4
docker-workflow:572.v950f58993843
durable-task:523.va_a_22cf15d5e0
echarts-api:5.4.0-5
email-ext:2.100
emailext-template:1.5
embeddable-build-status:412.v09da_db_1dee68
envinject:2.908.v66a_774b_31d93
envinject-api:1.199.v3ce31253ed13
extended-choice-parameter:376.v2e02857547b_a_
extensible-choice-parameter:1.8.0
external-monitor-job:203.v683c09d993b_9
favorite:2.4.1
filesystem_scm:2.1
folder-properties:1.2.1
font-awesome-api:6.4.0-2
forensics-api:2.3.0
gatling:1.3.0
ghprb:1.42.2
git:5.2.0
git-changelog:3.30
git-client:4.4.0
git-parameter:0.9.19
git-server:99.va_0826a_b_cdfa_d
github:1.37.3
github-api:1.314-431.v78d72a_3fe4c3
github-branch-source:1732.v3f1889a_c475b_
github-oauth:588.vf696a_350572a_
github-scm-trait-notification-context:1.1
gitlab-api:5.3.0-91.v1f9a_fda_d654f
gitlab-branch-source:671.v67b_7169092ca_
gitlab-plugin:1.7.12
golang:1.4
google-login:1.7
gradle:2.8.2
groovy-postbuild:2.5
h2-api:11.1.4.199-12.v9f4244395f7a_
handlebars:3.0.8
handy-uri-templates-2-api:2.1.8-22.v77d5b_75e6953
htmlpublisher:1.32
http_request:1.18
icon-shim:3.0.0
image-tag-parameter:2.0
influxdb:3.5
instance-identity:173.va_37c494ec4e5
ionicons-api:56.v1b_1c8c49374e
ivy:2.5
jackson2-api:2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595
jakarta-activation-api:2.0.1-3
jakarta-mail-api:2.0.1-3
javadoc:243.vb_b_503b_b_45537
javax-activation-api:1.2.0-6
javax-mail-api:1.6.2-9
jaxb:2.3.8-1
jdk-tool:73.vddf737284550
jenkins-design-language:1.27.5.1
jersey2-api:2.40-1
jira:3.10
jira-steps:2.0.165.v8846cf59f3db
jjwt-api:0.11.5-77.v646c772fddb_0
jnr-posix-api:3.1.16-2
job-dsl:1.84
jquery:1.12.4-1
jquery-detached:1.2.1
jquery3-api:3.7.0-1
jsch:0.2.8-65.v052c39de79b_2
junit:1217.v4297208a_a_b_ce
kubernetes:4007.v633279962016
kubernetes-cli:1.12.0
kubernetes-client-api:6.4.1-215.v2ed17097a_8e9
kubernetes-credentials:0.10.0
ldap:694.vc02a_69c9787f
lockable-resources:1185.v0c528656ce04
mailer:463.vedf8358e006b_
mapdb-api:1.0.9-28.vf251ce40855d
mask-passwords:150.vf80d33113e80
matrix-auth:3.2
matrix-project:808.v5a_b_5f56d6966
maven-plugin:3.23
mercurial:1260.vdfb_723cdcc81
metrics:4.2.18-442.v02e107157925
mina-sshd-api-common:2.10.0-69.v28e3e36d18eb_
mina-sshd-api-core:2.10.0-69.v28e3e36d18eb_
momentjs:1.1.1
monitoring:1.95.0
nodejs:1.6.1
oic-auth:2.6
okhttp-api:4.11.0-157.v6852a_a_fa_ec11
p4:1.14.2
pam-auth:1.10
parallel-test-executor:418.v24f9a_141d726
parameterized-trigger:2.46
pipeline-aws:1.43
pipeline-build-step:505.v5f0844d8d126
pipeline-github:2.8-147.3206e8179b1c
pipeline-graph-analysis:202.va_d268e64deb_3
pipeline-groovy-lib:671.v07c339c842e8
pipeline-input-step:477.v339683a_8d55e
pipeline-maven:1322.v9ef317a_3e0a_9
pipeline-milestone-step:111.v449306f708b_7
pipeline-model-api:2.2144.v077a_d1928a_40
pipeline-model-declarative-agent:1.1.1
pipeline-model-definition:2.2144.v077a_d1928a_40
pipeline-model-extensions:2.2144.v077a_d1928a_40
pipeline-rest-api:2.33
pipeline-stage-step:305.ve96d0205c1c6
pipeline-stage-tags-metadata:2.2144.v077a_d1928a_40
pipeline-stage-view:2.33
pipeline-utility-steps:2.16.0
plain-credentials:143.v1b_df8b_d3b_e48
plugin-util-api:3.3.0
popper-api:1.16.1-3
popper2-api:2.11.6-2
prism-api:1.29.0-4
promoted-builds:892.vd6219fc0a_efb
pubsub-light:1.17
purge-build-queue-plugin:88.v23b_97b_f2c7a_d
rebuild:320.v5a_0933a_e7d61
resource-disposer:0.23
run-condition:1.6
saml:4.429.v9a_781a_61f1da_
sbt:81.vb_82499046630
scm-api:676.v886669a_199a_a_
script-security:1273.v66c1964f0dfd
simple-theme-plugin:160.vb_76454b_67900
slack:684.v833089650554
snakeyaml-api:1.33-95.va_b_a_e3e47b_fa_4
sonar:2.15
sse-gateway:1.26
ssh-agent:333.v878b_53c89511
ssh-credentials:308.ve4497b_ccd8f4
ssh-slaves:2.916.vd17b_43357ce4
sshd:3.312.v1c601b_c83b_0e
stashNotifier:1.439.v202358346a_7d
structs:325.vcb_307d2a_2782
subversion:2.17.3
swarm:3.40
throttle-concurrents:2.14
timestamper:1.26
token-macro:384.vf35b_f26814ec
trilead-api:2.84.v72119de229b_7
variant:59.vf075fe829ccb
whitesource:21.1.2
windows-slaves:1.8.1
workflow-aggregator:596.v8c21c963d92d
workflow-api:1267.vd9b_a_ddd9eb_47
workflow-basic-steps:1042.ve7b_140c4a_e0c
workflow-cps:3773.v505e0052522c
workflow-cps-global-lib:609.vd95673f149b_b
workflow-durable-task-step:1289.v4d3e7b_01546b_
workflow-job:1326.ve643e00e9220
workflow-multibranch:756.v891d88f2cd46
workflow-remote-loader:1.6
workflow-scm-step:415.v434365564324
workflow-step-api:639.v6eca_cd8c04a_a_
workflow-support:848.v5a_383b_d14921
ws-cleanup:0.45
xvfb:1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

After investigating more and isolating some steps, we found that is an internal call to curl trying to post to our Slack with an expired token.

Something like:

```
script sh: "curl --fail --connect-timeout 20 --max-time 40 --retry 5 --retry-delay 10 --retry-max-time 40 -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @${filename} ${url}"
```

When curl fails, it returns exit code 22, but all the rest is the generic build error due the aborted build. This part is a legacy and will be replaced by [http_request](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/).

Regards!